# Difference between setting an attribute and calling an in-place mutating method?

Tags: python, class, numpy, oop, attributes

I mainly use numpy for doing data analysis, do don't understand the underlying program well, so this might be obvious.

I don't understand the difference between setting an attribute by simply assigning it vs. calling a method that changes that attribute in-place.  The example where you can do both is:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
   ...:               [4, 5, 6]])

In [3]: a.shape
Out[3]: (2, 3)

In [4]: a.reshape(3,2)
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

In [5]: a
Out[5]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [6]: a.resize(3,2)

In [7]: a
Out[7]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

In [8]: a.shape = (6,)

In [9]: a
Out[9]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

In [10]: a.__setattr__('shape',(3,2))

In [11]: a
Out[11]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

I don't understand what the difference is between inputs `6` and `8`.  Clearly both change the `a.shape` attribute in place, as opposed to returning the reshaped object as in `4`.  Do they both only call on `a.__setattr__()` as in `10`?  If so, why do they both exist?

(I am aware that `a.resize()` has the additional capacity to increase or decrease the memory allocated, but I'm not using that here --- does this duplicity only exist with the method adds some other capacity?)

Comment: Take a look at the source: http://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.7.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L108

Comment: I guess I want the `def resize` line actually: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.7.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L817

Comment: Both of those sources are for the standalone `numpy` functions, which have perfectly understandable behavior.  It's the method vs. setting attribute I don't understand.  It might be hidden in the [`c` source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/shape.c) but I don't know how to translate the `c` code into how the `class` attribute is changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read your question several times now and think I can address everything:

```
a.reshape(3,2)
# returns a new array

a.resize(3,2)
# returns None, operates on the same array
# (equivalent to modifying ndarray.shape here since no. of elements is unchanged)

a.shape = (6,)
# operates on the same array, uses property trick to hide detailed 
# setter logic behind normal attribute access.  
# note the parens are unnecessary here - equivalent is a.shape = 6,
# NOT equivalent to a = a.reshape(6,), which would change the id(a)

a.__setattr__('shape',(3,2))
# just an ugly way of doing a.shape = 3,2
```

Your main question seems to be about the non-uniqueness of methods to change the shape of the array.

> Clearly both change the a.shape attribute in place, as opposed to returning the reshaped object as in 4

Yes.  Or more accurately, both change the array in place (and the value returned by the `shape` "attribute" is modified as a consequence).

> Do they both only call on `a.__setattr__()` as in 10?

It is not strictly necessary for them to call `a.__setattr__(...)`.  They could change some internal `self._shape` variable instead, and it can still alter what is returned by `a.shape`.

You can see who does actually use `__setattr__` by creating your own class, e.g.:

```
class my_ndarray(np.ndarray):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print '__setattr__ called with name={}, value={}'.format(name, value)
        super(my_ndarray, self).__setattr__(name, value)

a_ = my_ndarray(a.shape)
a_[:] = a
```

In this case, the answer is that neither `a_.resize` nor `a_.reshape` uses `__setattr__`.

> **If so, why do they both exist?**

The fact that `resize` can do so much more than reshaping when the number of elements are different is reason enough for me.  It would be strange to use resize when all you needed to do was use reshape, but why should numpy (which is supposed to be high-performance) bother to warn you or artificially restrict you from using resize when you "could" be using reshape instead?

If you are concerned about the apparent violation of *zen of python #13*, `numpy` is not the best place to look for consistencies.  Just compare `np.eye` and `np.identity`, for example!   What's numpythonic isn't always pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

The example in 8 is actually called a [property](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), which python gives you access to in versions 2.1+.

e.g.

```
@property
def shape(self):
    """I'm the 'shape' property."""
    return self._shape

@shape.setter
def shape(self, value):
    self._shape = value
```

`__setattr__` invokes a `setter`:

```
x.__setattr__('shape', value)
```

is equivalent to (look at property setter above).

```
x.shape = value
```

The underlying logic always invokes a modifier function.

Comment: Cool thanks!  So if the `shape.setter` property is created, why also have yet another method, `resize`?

Comment: @askewchan You should ask that question the people that wrote the module. I am not familiar with numpy sorry :(

Comment: @askewchan  np.ndarray.resize is a different thing, it reallocates space for the data area if necessary.  reshape is used for the same number of elements, but np.ndarray.resize and np.resize don't have this restriction.

Comment: @wim I am aware, as mentioned in the question, of the additional capacities of `ndarray.resize()`  I guess what I'm looking for is some consistency between when a function or method changes the object in place or not, and perhaps numpy is not a good place to find such consistencies.

Comment: yes, `numpy` has all kinds of syntactic sugar that is not at all pythonic.  have a look at the interfaces for `np.c_` and `np.r_` index tricks for example, and scratch your head!